# XAMPP Mysql fix a default error

Tags: mysql, xampp

Whenever i try to edit something in Mysql in Browse tab mysql gives me this error `UPDATE Comments SET Likes = '1241' WHERE  LIMIT 1` i have to click the pop-up div and add 1 after `WHERE`.I have been having this error since i installed XAMPP.Is there anyway to change it so that it'll add 1 automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking the wrong question.

If you are not using a condition to filter on, you don't need the `where` clause.

```
SET Likes = '1241' LIMIT 1
```

should just work fine and produce the same result as your query. However, I'm not entirely sure either will update the row you want updated, as they literally take the first row, update it and then stop.